# UITableViewCell Button is not Clickable IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, interface-builder

So basically I am trying to do this:

I have a TableView that I load a custom cell (xib) into it. This custom cell has its own corresponding custom class to go with it. The cell loads just fine but the button is not clickable (at all, as in you don't even see any type of indication that the button was clicked at all). I did some googling, tried to set the action in the cell, tried using a delegate to handle the action. I am lost.

Here is the code from the files:

**ViewController.swift**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Use your cell's reuse identifier and cast the result
        // to your custom table cell class.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReserveTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReserveTableViewCell

        cell.delegate = self

        let button = cell.locationButton.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
        button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReserveTableViewController.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        cell.pickupDate.text = "Today"
        cell.returnDate.text = "Tomorrow"

        //cell.locationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loc), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)


        return cell
    }

func loc(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("here")
}
```

**CustomCell.swift**

```
import UIKit


protocol ReserveTableViewCellDelegate {
    func pickupLocationClick(cell: ReserveTableViewCell)
}

class ReserveTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var compactIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var midsizeIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var suvIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var luxuryIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sportIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickupIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickupDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var returnDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: ReserveTableViewCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func locationButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.pickupLocationClick(self)
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Some code is still left from other attempts (which is why the protocol method doesn't match the "loc" that is now defined in the viewcontroller.swift file.

In my TableView in storyboard I have selection turned off, when it is on and you tab on the cell it makes it all look "dim" so to speak.

I have the custom class set in my tableview and the outlets/actions are link in IB.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is possible to add functionality to the button in both the Cell file and in the ViewController file (which holds your TableView as a member)

**ViewController.swift**

```
@IBAction func locationButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Do Some Action Here (Which interacts with data members of View
}
```

**CustomCell.swift**

```
@IBAction func locationButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Do Another Action (Which interacts with data members of the cell)
}
```

Both of these functions can be linked to the TouchUpInside of the Cell button using the Storyboard Editor!

Best of luck!

Comment: I've tried both. For some reason it's like I just cannot get it to let me click the button? It's at the top of the view stack so I know it isnt hidden.

Comment: When you are in the Storyboard, are you able to use the Assistant Editor on the right to add the function to the 'Sent Events' section under TouchUpInside?

Comment: I'll try here in just a moment and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, I can. I had already had the TouchUpInside set to the button

Comment: Perfect. Is the button you are trying to create visible in the ContentView of the cell? (Usually found through the storyboard on clicking the Prototype Cell)

Comment: As in to find it you have to look TableView>CustomCell>ContentView>Button in the Storyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118583/discussion-between-jfed8-and-imperialized).

Answer (score 0):

Couple confusing things here...

```
let button = cell.locationButton.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
```

This means, hey locationButton, look in your subviews to find viewWithTag of 1.  Not what you want.  Just use

```
let button = cell.locationButton
```

Then you need to decide what action you're calling and what class does it live in.  If you want the button to call an action in the ViewController class you add a target like:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

If you want the button to call an action inside the ReserveTableViewController class, which honestly is pretty odd, you need a way to reference that class

```
button.addTarget(myReferenceToTheReserveTableViewControllerClass, action: #selector(ReserveTableViewController.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

What you may be actually looking for is for the button to call a method inside the cell class, in which you can then respond as necessary or delegate out to another class, which would then be:

```
button.addTarget(cell, action: #selector(ReserveTableViewCell.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: What is the reason for the button not being clickable? (for reference, it is at the "top" of the views stack. so I know it isnt hidden behind anything. Like if I make a view and add a button, even if I dont do anything to do, I can see that I clicked it. I dont see that here. Any ideas?

Comment: One other thing, is that you are correct (I did initially want it in the cell class, but couldn't get it to work there so i tried moving it)

Comment: I set up a project just like yours with a button in a custom XIB file.  The button doesn't appear clickable if you tap it quickly.  Press and hold on it and it should show the change.  Selection on my tableview is also set to none.

Comment: I'll check that out here in a second. yes, selection is set to none already.

Comment: This did not work either. It honestly seems like the button, for some reason, just isn't even noticing a "click" at all. -- A side note, thank you for explaining what that viewWithTag is.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up project just like you did. One thing i noticed in your in **ViewController.swift** is that you have written following code.

```
let button = cell.locationButton.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton //If you will print or debug this button you will see nil
print("Button: \(button)") //prints "Button: nil"
button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReserveTableViewController.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Above code is not adding target for your Button. It is adding target for your Buttons subview which has tag value 1. Which is actually nil. Try following code.

```
cell.locationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReserveTableViewController.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)(self, action: #selector(clicked), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Try the following code in your ViewController.swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Use your cell's reuse identifier and cast the result
    // to your custom table cell class.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReserveTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReserveTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self

    //let button = cell.locationButton.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton
    //button?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ReserveTableViewController.loc(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.locationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loc), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell.pickupDate.text = "Today"
    cell.returnDate.text = "Tomorrow"


    return cell
}
func loc(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("here")
}
```

Comment: It seems like the button just isn't accepting or noticing a "click" event at all.

Comment: Thats strange. That print statement has nothing to do with your button. It should be called any way if your cells are loaded. It is being called by your UITableViewDatasource. Is your TableView cells are loaded and visible?

Comment: Is there anyway you can share your sample project?

Comment: I put together a sample project for this (that isnt the actual program because I still can't get it sorted out. Let me upload and link it. Download is available here https://www.dropbox.com/s/57at9uri4fujcof/TableViewButtonTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Okay i made it work. First thing in your code you are using Empty.xib which UIView. And you are using that as UITableViewCell. Try with Cell.xib file which is UITableViewCell. Also don't forget to give reusableIdentifier to cell of Cell.xib. and also connect button outlet from Cell to TableCellTest.

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: To be completely honest, I am not sure what exactly was causing the problem. I rebuilt the nib, loaded it EXACTLY the same way, connected up the outlets/actions and it worked just fine. Gosh, the headache I could have avoided if I just redid it. I think it was related to the way I created the files, though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that was the problem which i mentioned. You were loading UIView instead of UITableViewCell in your table view. I am glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Yeah, I do believe that was it. Even though I had changed it in the code to be UITableViewCell (maybe not in the demo project I uploaded, but in the real one it was) - I must have missed something along the way. Thanks for the help.